# Java replaceall regex issue

Tags: java, replaceall

I am trying to add a letter to each consonant, the issue I do have is that I cannot figure out how I should add different for lowercase and uppercase.

Can I use double regex for this? in that case, how?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      skapar en scanner
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Skriv en rad text: ");
//      tar användarens input och översätter den till rövarspråket.
        String input = sc.nextLine();   
        System.out.println(input.replaceAll("([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])", "$1o$1"));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us an input output example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is a extracted excerpt for a larger program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScratchJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Skriv en rad text: ");
        String input = sc.nextLine();
        String intermediate = input.replaceAll("([bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz])", "$1o$1");
        System.out.println(intermediate.replaceAll("([BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ])", "$1X$1"));
    }
}
```

You can replace in two passes one for lower case other for upper case.

I couldn't find a method in standard library which would replace in same pass based on condition of match, though that would be much faster for a large input. Consider writing one yourself if you hit performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you use OR (`|`) in your regex

```
[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]|[BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXZ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `|` symbol to match either lower case or upper case characters.

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String text    =
      "John writes about this, and John Doe writes about that," +
      " and John Wayne writes about everything."
      ;

    String patternString1 = "([b-z&&[^eiou]]|[B-Z&&[^EIOU]])";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    String replaceAll = matcher.replaceAll("$10$1");
    System.out.println("replaceAll   = " + replaceAll);
  }
}
```

Output

```
replaceAll   = J0Joh0hn0n w0wr0rit0tes0s ab0bout0t t0th0his0s, an0nd0d J0Joh0hn0n D0Doe w0wr0rit0tes0s ab0bout0t t0th0hat0t, an0nd0d J0Joh0hn0n W0Way0yn0ne w0wr0rit0tes0s ab0bout0t ev0ver0ry0yt0th0hin0ng0g.
```

Comment: Hi. What I need is that lowercase have one letter e.g replaceall = joj and uppercase one letter e.g replaceall = JOJ